# Prevent www.win32.cn/g9 being run automatically

Tags: virus, rootkit

I have recently bought an a4 tech wireless mouse + keyboard. Everything was working fine, but when i started cmd as admin, i started getting the run command automatically and it executes www.win32.cn/g9 which opens my browser to get me on a4 tech web page. Can you please suggest how can i stop this.

Comment: I've tried to use info from http://malwaretips.com/blogs/win32-downloader-gen-trojan/, followed the steps but in vain

Comment: Did you install any drivers?

Comment: @DanielB , yes i think that this is related to the driver that  I have installed for my mouse +  keyboard. However i find this a bit unsual because i actually installed the driver since ( was done automatically ), but i started getting this when i started cmd as admin. Also when i disconnect the device i stop getting the run being automatically executed.

Comment: Uninstall the driver, does the behavior stop? If it does return the mouse for a refund and buy one that does not need an additional driver.